# Pass data to only static storyboard embedded tableview controller on a UINavigation

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, segue, uistoryboardsegue

So all my controller's are done programmatically to avoid segues and that sort of complicated stuff.

I have a viewcontroller (Call it **ProfileViewController**) that downloads data from the network.

So I have a method in **ProfileViewController** that instantiates a single storyboard file with a static `tableview` with cells that have textfields in them. Here is the method:

**ProfileViewController:**

```
func userSelectedUpdateProfile() {

   // Obtain reference to the only storyboard file named EditProfileSB
   let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "EditProfileSB", bundle: nil)

   // Since the Tableview is embedded in a navigation controller (with ID set to "navigationID")
   if let parentNavigationController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "navigationID") as? UINavigationController {

        // Now find the embedded TableViewController and access it's properties to pass to.
        if let childEditController = parentNavigationController.topViewController as? EditProfileTableViewController {

            // ! Error here ! Found nil when doing this.
            childEditController.nameTextfield.text = "Passed this to static cell"

        }
       present(parentNavigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

So the code itself is self-explanatory to what I am trying to achieve here. The TableView is embedded in a Navigation (done on storyboard with "Editor > Embed In") so on the 2nd nested `if let` statement I am now checking to find that Edit controller and access its properties (nameTextfield).

I get a crash when I attempt to access the `nameTextField.text` property. This textfield is set using storyboard. Here is that **EditProfileTableViewController:**

```
class EditProfileTableViewController: UITableViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var nameTextfield: UITextField!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  }

  // Other methods ...
}
```

Here is the storyboard flow layout.
[image]

Am I missing something here? I keep getting a crash on `childEditController.nameTextfield.text = "Passed this to static cell"` on the method `userSelectedUpdateProfile()`.

Comment: most probably is that nameTextfield is nil, the solution will be add  on EditProfileTableViewController the variable "var name : String = "" " and childEditController. name = "Passed this to static cell" so finally in the viewdidload of EditProfileTableViewController add nameTextfield.text = name.

Comment: Thanks mate, this worked.

Comment: this happen because you are trying to use nameTextField when this is nil, please try to read about the life cycle of ViewController

Answer (score 0):

If your View Controller still not call viewDidLoad().
your textfield is not create.

```
@IBOutlet weak var nameTextfield: UITextField!
```

you can see it's attribute is weak here.
Try create a value and pass text to the value. Then in viewDidLoad(), you can set the value to your textField